# Always have width on floating elements without text

Tags: html, css, width

Consider this:

```
<style>
a
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
<div>
    <a>First</a>
    <a>Second</a>
    <a>Third</a>
</div>
```

This works perfectly, and each `<a>` has the correct width. But when I remove the text from one of those `<a>`, the width gets lost, and instead of having 600px width, I have 400px.

What should I do to have 3 `<a>` with fixed width and without text?

I use jQuery a lot in my application and the text in those anchors changes.

I found a way of solving this by replacing the text with `\xA0`, but I can still click it, and I want it to be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the element ends up with no `height` without any content. The fix would be to specify a height:

```
a {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply `display: inline-block` to those anchors to prevent them to occupy less space.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `display:block;`

a tags is by default `display:inline;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:block for the style tag.
          Here is my take on it. 
                  http://jsfiddle.net/DkL6F/

```
             <div>
                <a style="background:#FF433F;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                <a style="background:#F1F33F;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                   <a style="background:#F1B33F;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            </div>

                  a
            {
                 float:left;
                width:200px;
                 text-align:center;
           display:block;

                }
```